# Angularjs datepicker directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hey I am new to angularjs directives,
I have the following code which need to be reused again and again over more than 10 pages.
I have tried to create some kind of simple directive , I used the html as template and tried to operate the same javascript code in the link function.
apparently I am doing some thing wrong here and I don't understand the full concepts of directives in angularjs.
I would be happy for any suggestion on how to build the link function properly.

```js
$(function () {
    //search for all date wrappers
    $(".date-wrapper").each(function (index) {
        console.log('index', index);
        $input = $(this).find('input');
        $btn = $(this).find('.calendar');

        console.log('input', $input[0]);
        console.log('btn', $btn[0]);

        $input.attr('type', 'text');
        var pickerStart = new Pikaday({
            field: $input[0],
            trigger: $btn[0],
            container: $(this)[0],
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            firstDay: 1
        });
        $btn.show();
    });
});
```

```css
   .dates-wrapper {
        background: white;
        padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;
        display: inline-block;
        width:100%;
        min-height: 60px;
    }
     
    .date-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 42px 10px 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .date-wrapper >.label {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 28px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        display:table;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .input {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #333;
        max-width: 172px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2px 10px;
    
    }
    .fieldWrapper {
        display: inline-flex;
        height: 26px; 
        color: #545454;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -o-box-sizing: border-box;   
        box-sizing: border-box;         
        border: 1px solid #ECF0F1;
        -moz-border-radius:3px;
        -webkit-border-radius:3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .fieldWrapper  a {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
        margin:6px;
        flex: none;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
   
 
    .fieldWrapper .calendar { 
        background-image: url('../images/ic_calendar.png');
        background-position:0 0;

    }
    .fieldWrapper 
    .calendar:hover,
    .fieldWrapper 
    .calendar:focus{ 
       background-position:0 -14px; 

    }
```

```html
<div class="dates-wrapper">
            <div class="date-wrapper">
                <label for="datepicker-start">From:</label>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    <input id="datepicker-start" type="date" placeholder="Select date" />
                    <a class="calendar"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="date-wrapper">
                <label for="datepicker-end">To:</label>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    <input id="datepicker-end" type="date" placeholder="Select date" />
                    <a class="calendar"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am adding the directive which I built so far

```
angular.module('directives', []).directive('datepicker', ['', function(){
// Runs during compile
return {
    scope: {
        id: '@',
        class: '@',
        LabelOne: '@',
        LabelTwo: '@'
    },
     restrict: 'E', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
     template: '<div id="{{id}}" class="{{class}}">'+
                '<div class="date-wrapper">'+
                    '<label for="datepicker-start">{{LabelOne}}:</label>'+
                    '<div class="fieldWrapper">'+
                        '<input id="datepicker-start" type="date" placeholder="Select date" />'+
                        '<a class="calendar"></a>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="date-wrapper">' +
                    '<label for="datepicker-end">{{LabelTwo}}:</label>' +
                    '<div class="fieldWrapper">' +
                        '<input id="datepicker-end" type="date" placeholder="Select date" />' +
                        '<a class="calendar"></a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'
                ,
    link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {


        $(".date-wrapper").each(function (index) {
            console.log('index', index);
            $input = $(this).find('input');
            $btn = $(this).find('.calendar');

            console.log('input', $input[0]);
            console.log('btn', $btn[0]);

            $input.attr('type', 'text');
            var pickerStart = new Pikaday({
                field: $input[0],
                trigger: $btn[0],
                container: $(this)[0],
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                firstDay: 1
            });
            $btn.show();
        });
    }
};
```

}]);

Comment: What is currently happening? Is plugin working on input? Any errors in console? Need more details of problem. Note that `class` is a reserved word in javascript and should always be quoted in object property names

Comment: no errors, the directive just generate the template but the javascript code in the link function doesn't executed as excpected.

Comment: No console logging even? Is there an element `<datepicker></datepicker>`? Your `restrict` is looking for that

Comment: I will put some console.log for debug. Can you tell me if my code in the linking funtion will work or should I rewrite it? if so how to write it in form of the angular way?

Comment: For starters is there an element like I asked about? i'm not sure what you are attaching this directive to.

Comment: there is an element <datepicker></datepicker>

Comment: and anything logging to console from just inside link? Might need to try using `$timeout` to wrap the jquery but it really should work as is assuming the plugin is configured properly